# Update the value of an key in object for all occurancecs

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am trying to update the price inside the array, my objective is to update the price for all the occurrence of ID.

```
finalbrarray : [    
        { id: 136, name: 'Chocolate - Chips Compound', price: '235.92' },
        { id: 137, name: 'Appetizer - Chicken Satay', price: '199.69' },
        { id: 138, name: 'Compound - Mocha', price: '431.16' },
        { id: 139, name: 'Syrup - Chocolate', price: '427.25' },
        { id: 139, name: 'Syrup - Chocolate', price: '427.25' },
        { id: 140, name: 'Lamb - Leg, Boneless', price: '183.44' },
        { id: 141, name: 'Jam - Blackberry, 20 Ml Jar', price: '493.03' },
        { id: 142, name: 'Lid - 3oz Med Rec', price: '259.42' }
      ]
```

I am trying to update the price with following function:

```
  const handleTextClick = id => e => {
    const objIndex = finalbrArray.findIndex(br => br.id === id);
    finalbrArray[objIndex].price = e.target.value;
    const updatedObj = { ...finalbrArray[objIndex], price: e.target.value };
    console.log(updatedObj);

    console.table(finalbrArray);
  };
```

This updates the first occurrence of the "id:139" i.e index 3..

I want to be able to change the value at both index 3 and 4..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using filter to get a subset of the matching values. `findIndex` will return the index of first occurrence inside an array.

```js
var finalbrarray = [{
    id: 136,
    name: 'Chocolate - Chips Compound',
    price: '235.92'
  },
  {
    id: 137,
    name: 'Appetizer - Chicken Satay',
    price: '199.69'
  },
  {
    id: 138,
    name: 'Compound - Mocha',
    price: '431.16'
  },
  {
    id: 139,
    name: 'Syrup - Chocolate',
    price: '427.25'
  },
  {
    id: 139,
    name: 'Syrup - Chocolate',
    price: '427.25'
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Lamb - Leg, Boneless',
    price: '183.44'
  },
  {
    id: 141,
    name: 'Jam - Blackberry, 20 Ml Jar',
    price: '493.03'
  },
  {
    id: 142,
    name: 'Lid - 3oz Med Rec',
    price: '259.42'
  }
]

// I'm passing id 139 for example. & setting the value to '500'

// filter returns an array where the criteria matches, then I'm calling forEach on new array returned by fiter and changing the values of price
finalbrarray.filter(br => br.id === 139).forEach((item) => {
  item.price = '500'
})

// Open console to see the values updated
console.table(finalbrarray);
```

Open the console to see the values being updated

Answer (score 1):

`findIndex` finds the first occurrence of the predicate.
You can achieve your goal with `map`:

```js
const arr = [    
        { id: 136, name: 'Chocolate - Chips Compound', price: '235.92' },
        { id: 137, name: 'Appetizer - Chicken Satay', price: '199.69' },
        { id: 138, name: 'Compound - Mocha', price: '431.16' },
        { id: 139, name: 'Syrup - Chocolate', price: '427.25' },
        { id: 139, name: 'Syrup - Chocolate', price: '427.25' },
        { id: 140, name: 'Lamb - Leg, Boneless', price: '183.44' },
        { id: 141, name: 'Jam - Blackberry, 20 Ml Jar', price: '493.03' },
        { id: 142, name: 'Lid - 3oz Med Rec', price: '259.42' }
      ];
    
const update = (arr, id, value) => arr.map(it => it.id === id ? (it.price=value, it) : it);

console.log(update(arr, 139, 100))
```